# Looping through formdata in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, loops, for-loop, multipartform-data

I am trying to loop through formdata, I have read several times that I should be able to use FormData in a for ... of ... loop, however when I try, I get the error:

```
Type 'FormData' is not an array type or a string type
```

My code:

```
export class NewsCreationComponent implements OnInit {

  fileToUpload: File = null;
  uploadImages = new FormData();

...

  handleFile(event) {
    this.fileToUpload = event.target.files;
    this.uploadImages.append(this.fileToUpload.name, this.fileToUpload);
  }

  save() {
    for (let up of this.uploadImages) {
      this.imageService.createImage(up)
      });
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your FormData initialization `uploadImages = new FormData();` to the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook, so you are sure that is is defined when your `save()` function is called.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, however when I try your solution it does not work because adding .entries() gives the error: Property 'entries' does not exist on type 'FormData'. Any guess?

Comment: Moving the definition of uploadImages to ngOnInit() solved the problem, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Glad to be of help :) - I have updated my answer to reflect that